# Docker share environment variables using volumes

Tags: docker, environment-variables

How can I share environment variables since the `--link` feature was deprecated?
The Docker documentation (https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) states

> Warning: The `--link` flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may
>   eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using
>   it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate
>   communication between two containers instead of using `--link`. One
>   feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with
>   `--link` is sharing environment variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment
>   variables between containers in a more controlled way.

But how do I share environment variable  by using volumes? I did not find anything about environment variables in the volumes section.

The problem that I have is that I want to set a database password as environment variable when I start the container. Some other container loads data into the database and for that needs to connect to it and provide the credentials. So far the loading container discovered the password on its own by reading the environment variable. How do I do that now without `--link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you do it by explicitly providing the same environment variable to other containers.  This is easy if you're using a `docker-compose.yml` to manage your containers, because then you can do this:

```
version: 3

services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

  frontend:
    image: webserver
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Then if you set `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` in your `.env` file, the same value will be provided to both the `database` and `frontend` container.  If you're not using `docker-compose`, you can still simplify things by using an environment file.  Create a file named, e.g., `database.env` that contains:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then point your containers at that using `docker run --env-file database.env ...`.

---

You can't share environment variables using volumes, but you can of course share *files*. So another option would be to have your database container write a file containing the password to a shared volume, and then read that in your other containers.

Comment: will this work if an environment variable is set from within one of the containers ?

Comment: No. An environment variable set inside a container cannot be seen by other containers.

Comment: But why it's written in the docker docs? `However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment variables`

Comment: Well, you can write your environment variables to a file in a shared volume, and then read that from another container.